# SUM total time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I have a problem with the `SUM` operator in SQL Server. When I write this query:

```
SELECT StudentID, StudentName, SUM(time) as 'TotalTime' 
FROM WorkNote
GROUP BY StudentID, StudentName
```

I get this error:

> Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator.

Is there some other method for `SUM` or to calculate the total times from the records?

In my `WorkNote` table, the type of column `time` is `Time(7)`, and I want to `SUM` all (total) times for every student.

Comment: The `time` data type represents a time of day, not an interval. It doesn't make sense to add times of day together - quick, what's 3:30pm plus 10:24 am? If you're storing intervals in columns of this type, then you're misusing it. It would be better to record the interval as a plain numeric type, as a total number of hours, minutes, seconds or milliseconds - whatever precision makes sense for your purposes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if the time in `hh/mm/ss` then ::

```
SELECT studentid,studentname,
         DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', mytime)), '00:00:00.000') as time
    FROM
         worknote
```

Comment: `DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, 0, mytime)), 0) as time` seems to be working correctly too but looks nicer.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn the time in seconds and sum that up.

```
SELECT   StudentID, 
         StudentName, 
         sum( DATEPART(SECOND, [time]) + 60 * 
              DATEPART(MINUTE, [time]) + 3600 * 
              DATEPART(HOUR, [time] ) 
            ) as 'TotalTime' 
FROM WorkNote
GROUP BY StudentID, StudentName
```

Comment: i get total like that: 1413
i want total time in hours like time1= 1:20:5 time2= 2:20:10 total time = 3: 40: 15

Comment: Put that please in your question in a well formatted manner.