# how to add some "time" variables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a "time" columns and I want to gain the summation of all rows. I used the code given below but it returned a big number. Do I use the right way? If yes, what does this number mean?

Code:

```
SELECT sum(`wpf_login`.exit) FROM `wpf_login`
```

Result: 914160

Table :

[image]

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: How you want to make a SUM over time data? What should be, in your view, SUM of 13:20:00 and 15:23:40? If you mean 28:43:40, it doesn´t make a sense...

Comment: a time... that shows hours and minutes and seconds... I even don't know what means this result!

Comment: @panther of course this "time" is difference between another 2 times... and I want to calculate the hours that the employee worked... so it make sense!

Comment: @mj-y .. Is it the complete table ? Maybe it has summed up the time in  terms of seconds..

Comment: @Noob yes it's the complete table

Comment: possible duplicate of [SUM total time in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535718/sum-total-time-in-sql-server)

Comment: OK, so you want to calculate how many hours a user worked? Why not just store both `entry` and `exit` as `DATETIME` types?

Comment: @noob that's sql server not mysql

Comment: @BenM what is the difference between datetime and time? at last I want to sum their hour difference...

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the time columns to datetime.

Then you could sum the difference between exit and entry:

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(`wpf_login`.exit, `wpf_login`.entry)) FROM `wpf_login`
```

The Result will be the total seconds worked.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: hey I used timediff ... it is not a god way to subtract 2 time like this... are you sure that the result is total second time?

Comment: You are right, just substracting the values won't work. But using TIMESTAMPDIFF on datetime fields seams to be the way, according to the mysql documentation. Just edited the answer.