# How to get subtotals with time datatype in SQL?

Tags: sql, time, firebird, subtotal

I get stuck generating a SQL query. I have a Table in a Firebird DB like the following one:

```
ID  | PROCESS | STEP | TIME  
654 |       1 |    1 | 09:08:40  
655 |       1 |    2 | 09:09:32  
656 |       1 |    3 | 09:10:04  
...  
670 |       2 |   15 | 09:30:05  
671 |       2 |   16 | 09:31:00
```

and so on.

I need the subtotals for each process group (It's about 7 of these). The table has the "time"-type for the TIME column.I have been trying it with DATEDIFF, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want your query to return the time spent by each step, or the time spent by each process?

Comment: By each process. I know I have to use SUM, but cant figure out in which combination with other SQL functions

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: you shown the reference source data - that is really good. Now please, add the reference result data you want to be generated, and step-by-step description how you do generate that result data from this your source data, for us to understand the process you describe

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SUM`

This question has been answered here.

[How to sum up time field in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9725732/2468342)

and here.

[SUM total time in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19535718/2468342)

For more specific Firebird documentation. Read up on the sum function here.

[Sum() - Firebird Official Documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs.html#fblangref25-funcs-tbl-sum)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been reading the posts and I tried the solutions without any success. When I try the solution from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9725732/2468342) I get an expression evaluation exception --> '0:00:00 is not a TIME type'

Comment: Post your query in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use "GROUP BY" to get max time and min time, and to use them in the datediff function. Something like that:

```
select process, datediff(second, max(time), min(time)) as nb_seconds
from your_table
group by process;
```