# Sum certain rows in sql

Tags: ssms

I want to sum different rows of my table into a different column. I have a Id column which have multiple times. When I try to sum the time table it says cannot sum time data type.

Here is what my query looks like atm:

```
 select t.Id,
        a.EndTime,
        cast(A.Endtime as time)[time]
    from [plugin.tickets].Ticket as T
    join
        [plugin.tickets].TicketActivity as TA ON TA.TicketId = T.Id
    join
    dbo.Activity as A on A.Id = TA.ActivityId
```

Here is the output of this query:

[image]

As you can see there are id numbers which have multiple times. How can I sum these values?

EDIT:
I have changed my query as following:

```
select  t.Id
        ,a.EndTime
        ,convert (varchar(5), EndTime,108) as Tijd
from [plugin.tickets].Ticket as T
join
    [plugin.tickets].TicketActivity as TA ON TA.TicketId = T.Id
join
dbo.Activity as A on A.Id = TA.ActivityId
```

I just want to sum these where the ID number is the same.

Thanks,

Shabby

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535718/sum-total-time-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the two functions DATEPART and DATEADD. I'm assuming your useing T-SQL here. So you would take the time field convert that to hour which would give you 17 for example and then use date add on the End Time field.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I want to add hour and minute aswell but with the datepart function I can only select hour OR minute...

Comment: Then either do multiple adds or you could change it to seconds.